# Как вытащить значение переменной из 2 класса и переместить в 3 класс?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer

После перехода на **`2`** окно и выбора *Excel* файла путь показывается, но когда перейдешь на **`3`** окно и попытке вывести путь к файлу, выдает ошибку, что переменная не найдена.

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QStackedWidget


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(426, 216)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 20, 160, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 334, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "перейти в следующие окно"))


class Ui_MainWindow1(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(426, 216)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(426, 216))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 40, 101, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 40, 151, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 90, 150, 51))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 110, 101, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 426, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "выбрать файл"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "посмотреть путь к файлу"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "следующие окно"))


class Ui_MainWindow2(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(334, 150)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 20, 150, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 60, 150, 31))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 334, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "посмотреть путь к фалу"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))


class MainWindow2(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow2):              
    def __init__(self, parent=None):                                          
        super().__init__(parent)                                               
        self.setupUi(self) 
        self.parent = parent                                                 

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.conclusion)

    def conclusion(self):
        self.label.setText(self.parent.name)                                


class MainWindow1(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow1):              
    def __init__(self, parent=None):                                         
        super().__init__(parent)                                               
        self.setupUi(self) 
        self.parent = parent                                                   
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.open_file)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.conclusion)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.onMainWindow2)
        self.mainWindow2 = MainWindow2(self.parent)                           

    def open_file(self):
        self.name, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Выберите файл', '.',  
            "Файлы Exсel (*.xlsx)") 

    def conclusion(self):
        self.label.setText(self.name)

    def onMainWindow2(self):
        self.conclusion()
        self.mainWindow2.show()    
        self.hide()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):                          
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)       

        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onMainWindow1)

        self.mainWindow1 = MainWindow1(self)                                 


    def onMainWindow1(self):
        self.mainWindow1.show()
        windows.hide()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    startmenu_window = MainWindow()
    windows = QStackedWidget()

    windows.addWidget(startmenu_window)  
    windows.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Сейчас на меня набегут global-зло'исты, но как вариант... Объявляешь переменную с адресом в `open_file` как `global global_name`, потом `global_name=StringVar()`, `global_name.set(name)`, дальше там где тебе надо добыть ставишь `global global_name`, `name = global_name.get()` и дальше уже там работаешь с переменной name. Естественно, на этапе того как будешь осваивать развешиваешь везде `print(name, global_name.get())` и смотришь что и где и как. PS Уважаемые товарищи global-зло'исты, мб подскажете как именно надо передавать данные между 2 независимыми блоками? Если первый НЕ вызывает второй?

Comment: @Gh0sTG0 глобальные переменные -это ЗЛО. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil

Comment: Я, пожалуй, пойду и задам это отдельным вопросом, таки. Т.к. по этой ссылке ответа на свой вопрос как это сделать НЕ глобальными переменными я чего то не нашел =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В классе `MainWindow1` определите `name`:

```
self.name = ''
```

тогда в классе `MainWindow2`:

```
self.label.setText(self.parent.mainWindow1.name)
```

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QStackedWidget


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(426, 216)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 20, 160, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 334, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "перейти в следующие окно"))


class Ui_MainWindow1(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(426, 216)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(426, 216))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 40, 101, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 40, 151, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 90, 150, 51))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 110, 101, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 426, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "выбрать файл"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "посмотреть путь к файлу"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "следующие окно"))


class Ui_MainWindow2(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(334, 150)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 20, 150, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 60, 150, 31))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 334, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "посмотреть путь к фалу"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))


class MainWindow2(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow2):              
    def __init__(self, parent=None):                                          
        super().__init__(parent)                                               
        self.setupUi(self) 
        self.parent = parent                                                 

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.conclusion)

    def conclusion(self):
#        self.label.setText(self.parent.name)  
        self.label.setText(self.parent.mainWindow1.name)         # <----                        


class MainWindow1(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow1):              
    def __init__(self, parent=None):                                         
        super().__init__(parent)                                               
        self.setupUi(self) 
        self.parent = parent                                                   
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.open_file)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.conclusion)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.onMainWindow2)
        self.mainWindow2 = MainWindow2(self.parent) 

        self.name = ''                                            # <----      

    def open_file(self):
        self.name, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Выберите файл', '.',  
            "Файлы Exсel (*.xlsx)") 

    def conclusion(self):
        self.label.setText(self.name)

    def onMainWindow2(self):
        self.conclusion()
        self.mainWindow2.show()    
        self.hide()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):                          
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)       

        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onMainWindow1)

        self.mainWindow1 = MainWindow1(self)                                 


    def onMainWindow1(self):
        self.mainWindow1.show()
        windows.hide()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    startmenu_window = MainWindow()
    windows = QStackedWidget()

    windows.addWidget(startmenu_window)  
    windows.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]