# Как мне передать флаг на остановку из GUI в Thread с циклом без global variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, global-variables

В продолжение темы о том, что global variables - зло. ([Вот тут в комментариях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1294723/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%B7-2-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-3-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81))

Допустим, я согласен с этим и не хочу их использовать в своей программе.

У меня есть GUI, из которого я осуществляю общее управление. При нажатии кнопки Старт в GUI у меня запускается Thread, в котором у меня стоит цикл, который для меня выполняет работу. Когда я нажимаю кнопку Стоп в GUI, мне нужно чтобы у меня цикл выполнил текущий проход, выполнил несколько действий и закончился.

Так же у меня идет передача информации о текущей активности в обратном направлении (в частности имя рабочего файла цикла пишется в Label в gui)

Сейчас я это реализовал через глобальную переменную-boolean, и проверку этой переменной в конце очередного прохода цикла.

Как эту передачу флага на остановку, или возврат имени рабочего файла, осуществить правильно? Не прибить программу, не прибить thread, а именно сделать так, чтобы цикл в определенном месте выполнит определенные действия и завершится?

Кусочки кода:

```
# В инициализации gui я задаю:
    global active_file_path
    active_file_path = StringVar()
    active_file_path.set("No active file now")
    
    active_file_way = ttk.Label(textvariable=active_file_path, anchor="center")
    active_file_way.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=E + W + N)

    global should_stop
    should_stop = BooleanVar()
    should_stop.set(False)

# В Thread'е я делаю каждый проход цикла:
    active_file_path.set(file_name)
# И в конце прохода:
    if should_stop.get():
    ...

# Кнопка Стоп делает:
    should_stop.set(True)
```

Update 1 (к комментариям):

Я задаю в описании gui текст через textvariable и позже этот textvariable меняю при необходимости:

```
class main_app(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        self.shared_state = SharedState()
        active_file_way = ttk.Label(textvariable=self.shared_state.active_file_path, anchor="center")

# В классе с флагом я задаю вот так:
class SharedState:
    def __init__(self):
        self.active_file_path = tk.StringVar()
        self.active_file_path.set("No active file now")

# И потом в цикле у меня стоит:
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    shared_state.active_file_path.set(file_address)
```

При таком использовании при вызове метода .set() текст в Label сразу изменяется.

Оно работает. Но нету ли с ним такого же расклада, как с работающими global'ами?

Почему спрашиваю - там где я это нашел, именно эти StringVar() и объявлялись как global, вот потому и спрашиваю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте (не глобальный) объект, через который будет происходить взаимодействие.

При создании потока передавайте ссылку на этот объект в функцию потока, тогда она сможет вызывать у этого объекта методы и изменять атрибуты. Условный код:

```
class SharedState:
   def __init__(self):
     self.finished = False


def background_job(shared_state):
   while not shared_state.finished:
     # работаем в цикле


class SomeUIComponent:
  def some_ui_function(self):
    self.shared_state = SharedState()
    thread = Thread(target=background_job, args(self.shared_state,))
    thread.start()
 
  def some_other_ui_function(self):
    self.shared_state.finished = True
```

Тот код, который создает поток, т.е. UI, тоже имеет доступ к этому объекту, ведь он его создал. Значить UI может читать из этого объекта значения атрибутов. То есть UI и фоновый поток могут между собой взаимодействовать через разделяемый объект, на который у них есть ссылки.

Важно только синхронизировать доступ к этому объекту, если важна атомарность операций изменения. Простой способ для передачи более сложных данных чем один флаг - это [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html).

Что касается использования `tk.StringVar` в `SharedState`, то тут нет никакого использования глобальных переменных. Если класс `tk.StringVar` потокобезопасный, то никаких проблем. Но я бы не вносил код, который знает что-то про UI (а `tk.StringVar` таким является) в `SharedState`. Лучше чтоб там были просто строки.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я попробую поэкспериментировать с этим делом, но несколько позже.

Comment: Такой вопрос еще сверху: А использование `self.some_variable = tk.StringVar()` и дальше к ней методов `.set("something")` и `.get` это ок? Или тоже куда то к глобалам и не юзать?

Comment: Все работает, спасибо.

Comment: Вопрос про методы не понял. Нужно больше подробностей

Comment: Добавил в update 1 в вопрос.