# Помогите решить задачу, функция должна остановить цикл while, который находится в другой функции

Tags: python

```
import time
import keyboard

Continue = True


def stop():
    print("stop")
    # Функция stop должна выдать глобальное значение False
    # для переменной Continue(во время работы цикла while)

keyboard.add_hotkey('esc', stop)


def start():
    print("start")
    while Continue:
        print("continue")
        time.sleep(2)


start()
```

Comment: Как то вот так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1294753/Как-мне-передать-флаг-на-остановку-из-gui-в-thread-с-циклом-без-global-variables

Answer (score 1):

Вставьте в функцию `stop` следущий код

```py
global Continue #говрим интерпретатору, что нужно работать с глобальной переменной, а не создавать переменную внутри функции 
Continue = False #присваиваем переменной значение False
```

Надеюсь, мой ответ был понятен и полезен)