# "Магазин" не работает

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

Делаю кликер с функцией апгрейда. Как только начал делать магазин, всё полетело. При нажатии на магазин, открывается новая кнопка И отправляется это:

> Вам не хватает
> Ваше число кликов: 32
> Вам не хватает
> Ваше число кликов: 32

Кнопка второй уровень вовсе не работает

```
import sqlite3
from random import randint
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

global db
global cu
db = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
cu = db.cursor()
window = tk.Tk()

cu.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
    login TEXT,
    password TEXT,
    cash INT
)""")
db.commit()


def menu():
    global user_login
    global password_login
    user_login = input('Ваше имя:')
    password_login = input('Ваш пароль:')
    cu.execute(f"SELECT login FROM user WHERE login = '{user_login}'")
    if cu.fetchone() is None:
        cu.execute(f"INSERT INTO user VALUES(?, ?, ?)", (user_login, password_login, 0))
        db.commit()
        text.insert(INSERT, "Регистрация успешна\n")
        text.pack()
        print("Успешно")
    else:
        text.insert(INSERT, f"Добро пожаловать, {user_login}\n")
        text.pack()
        print("Успешно")
        game()


def game():
    text.insert(INSERT, "Чтоб начать игру, нажмите на кнопку ниже\n")
    text.pack()
    tk.Button(window, text="Клик(1 уровень)", command=click1).place(x=200, y=40)
    tk.Button(window, text="Магазин", command=shop).place(x=500, y=40)


def game1():
    text.insert(INSERT, "Чтоб начать игру, нажмите на кнопку ниже\n")
    text.pack()
    tk.Button(window, text="Клик(1 уровень)", command=click1).place(x=200, y=40)
    tk.Button(window, text="Клик(2 уровень)", command=click2).place(x=200, y=70)
    tk.Button(window, text="Магазин", command=shop).place(x=500, y=40)


def click1():
    number = randint(1, 1)
    for i in cu.execute(f"SELECT cash FROM user WHERE login = '{user_login}'"):
        global cashe
        cashe = i[0]
    if number == 1:
        cu.execute(f"UPDATE user SET cash = {1 + cashe} WHERE login = '{user_login}'")
        text.insert(INSERT, f"\n\nВаше число кликов: {cashe}")
        db.commit()


def click2():
    number = randint(1, 1)
    if number == 1:
        cu.execute(f"UPDATE user SET cash = {2 + cashe} WHERE login = '{user_login}'")
        text.insert(INSERT, f"\n\nВаше число кликов: {cashe}")
        db.commit()


def shop():
    tk.Button(window, text="2 уровень").place(x=500, y=65)
    if cashe == 20:
        text.insert(INSERT, f"\nВы купили 2 уровень\nВаше число кликов: {cashe}")
        game1()
    else:
        text.insert(INSERT, f"\nВам не хватает\nВаше число кликов: {cashe}")
    tk.Button(window, text="3 уровень", command=shop).place(x=500, y=90)
```

Comment: А в def shop() ты откуда берешь значение cashe? Если ты их пихаешь в бд, то и получай. И еще, лучше обойтись без global переменных, про это здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1294753/Как-мне-передать-флаг-на-остановку-из-gui-в-thread-с-циклом-без-global-variables . Про global'ы - попробуй объявить global cashe прямо перед if в shop().

Comment: О, и как я мог проглядеть... Почему у тебя cashe `==` 20? Ты условие выставляешь что ТОЛЬКО если у тебя РОВНО 20 кликов можно купить. Ставь там `>=`

Comment: На первый комментарий отвечу так: приму к сведению про global. Я попробовал объявить global cash перед if, но результата нет

Comment: А про второе? Как там с точно равно?

Comment: @Gh0sTG0 Спасибо! Дело было в знаке

Comment: Хорошо, я тогда сейчас это чиркану в ответе, отметь что у тебя решено тогда.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В функции def shop():

```
def shop():
    tk.Button(window, text="2 уровень").place(x=500, y=65)
    if cashe == 20:
    ...
```

Сработка if'а возможна только при количестве кликов точно равном 20. Чтобы срабатывало при 20 и больше надо сделать вместо `cashe == 20` - `cashe >= 20`.

Comment: Очень благодарен вам!

Comment: Ну, и почитай таки как без global'ов обходиться, мб лучше зайдет, чем с ними.