# Как использовать while True: вместе с tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, сервер, сокет, while

Есть вот такой код:

```
while True:

user_socket, adress = server.accept()
```

но при использовании tkinter, окно tkinter замерзает, я нашел подобный вопрос в котором предложили использовать `threading`.
Но мне это не помогло

Comment: Покажите ваш скрипт. Как вы используете потоки.

Comment: Там нечего показывать, сверху над этим кодом root = tk.Tk() и код для создания ентри и кнопок

Comment: вот и весь скрипт

Comment: Приведите минимально воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: При котором ваше окно виснет.

Comment: 1) делаешь gui. 2) отдельно в def пишешь твой while. 3) этот def запускаешь в threading.

Comment: А что если GUI и код в while True должны взаимодействовать другс другом?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1294753/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7-gui-%d0%b2-thread-%d1%81-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-global-variables
Вот тебе и цикл в threading, и коммуникация с этим циклом.

Comment: можно подробнее что с этим сокетом потом делаешь. сколько клиентов должно ацептнуться - один или несколько?

Comment: потом через этот сокет я отправляю сообщения зашифрованные через utf-8, растчитанно все на 1 юзера