# Mожно ли связываться с родительским потоком из дочернего(threading)?

Tags: python, pyqt, asyncio, threading

Можно ли в дочернем потоке обращаться к родительскому и вызывать что то уже из него? Зачем мне это? Решил я написать простенький чат с графическим интерфейсом. В качестве сервера использовал модуль socket, а для интерфейса взял pyqt. Еще я использовал threading.Для чего? Для того чтобы мой сервер принимал подключения в отдельном потоке, т.е был независимым. Когда сообщение приходило я добавлял к нему "\n", для того чтобы сделать перенос строки. После этого я просто выводил это сообщение в поле textEdit, предварительно отключив возможность менять текст в этом поле. НО. Мой интерфейс был в главном потоке, а задавал я текст из дочернего. Ну мне и вывелась ошибка о том, что так нельзя. Я решил это асинхронностью, но все же стало интересно, можно ли было просто из дочернего вызвать метод setText(для записи в текста в поле) и не париться с асинхронностью? Если да, то как?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1294753/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7-gui-%d0%b2-thread-%d1%81-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-global-variables вот тут как реализовывать по идее. У меня так передается флаг из гуи в поток, и вызывается функция которая пишет из потока в гуи. Вот полный код того что я там делал, https://pastebin.com/YsJsYXym

Comment: Я в своем коде вызываю именно функцию которая делает вставку в гуи из потока. `log_info` называется.

Comment: Тут дело не в многопоточности самой по себе. Проблема в том, что методы  из qt можно вызывать только из gui потока.