# как реализовать цикл прослушивания с микрофона в kivy с дальнейшим распознанием и т.п

Tags: python, циклы, kivy, pyaudio, звукозапись

Создаю голосового помощника на Python и хотелось бы обернуть его в графический интерфейс. Использовал kivy.  При нажатии кнопки, которая запускает запись звука и распознавания(посредством цикла), графическое окно зависает и работает только консоль. Вопрос: возможно ли реализовать то, что я хочу в kivy, если да, то как? если нет, то какую оболочку для графического интерфейса использовать в данной задаче? (чтобы работали циклы, или чем их заменить и как?)

В коде ниже убрал всё лишнее, оставил только саму суть проблемы.

```
import json, pyaudio
from vosk import Model, KaldiRecognizer
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('kivy','keyboard_mode','systemanddock')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=16000, input=True, frames_per_buffer=8000)
stream.start_stream()

model_ru_small = Model('C:/1/Python/voice_helper/model_ru_small')
rec_ru_small = KaldiRecognizer(model_ru_small, 16000)

def listen():
    while True:
        data = stream.read(4000, exception_on_overflow=False)
        if (rec_ru_small.AcceptWaveform(data)) and (len(data)>0):
            answer_ru = json.loads(rec_ru_small.Result())
            if answer_ru['text']!='':
                yield answer_ru['text']

def m_n():
    for text in listen():
        print(text)
        if text!='':
            if text=='привет':
                print('привет')
                ## далее идут другие команды..

class MyApp(App):

    def btn_pressed(self, *args):
        m_n()

    def build(self):
        self.title = 'Голосовой помощник'
        box=BoxLayout()
        btn=Button(text='Запуск')
        btn.bind(on_press=self.btn_pressed)
        label=Label(text='Голосовой \n помощник \n 1.0')
        box.add_widget(label)
        box.add_widget(btn)
        return box

if __name__=='__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Тебе нужно разделить gui и всю работу которая занимает дольше ~1 секунды в разные потоки модулем Threading. В твоем случае тебе нужно делать listen в Thread отдельный. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1294753/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7-gui-%d0%b2-thread-%d1%81-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-global-variables вот тут в ответе есть как это запускать. (и заодно там же про то как обмениваться данными)

Comment: @Gh0sTG0,  спасибо, получилось!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def btn_pressed(self, *args):
    thread = Thread(target=m_n)
    thread.start()
```

При нажатии на кнопку открываю новый поток, который содержит в себе бесконечный цикл прослушки.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]