# Python [Kivy]: Проблема с циклом while True

Tags: python, kivy

У меня есть программа, которая считает секунды с нажатия кнопки, но при нажатии кнопки, вместо того чтобы считать секунды, программа просто зависает. Как это исправить?

**Код**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.base import Builder
from time import sleep

class main(App):
  def go(self):
    i = 0
    while True:
      i += 1
      self.main.ids.i.text = str(i)
      sleep(1)
  def build(self):
    self.main = Builder.load_string("""
BoxLayout:
    Label:
        text: "-"
        id: i
    Button:
        on_press: app.go()
        text: "go"
        id: run
""")
    return self.main

main().run()
```

Comment: У тебя гуи и цикл выполняются в одном потоке. Естественно, гуи ждет пока выполнится действие. А оно не выполнится. Запихиваешь свой бесконечный цикл в отдельную функцию, стартуешь функцию через Threading, наслаждаешься тем, что у тебя гуй и цикл работают отдельно. Там же по ссылке есть про то, как правильно обмениваться данными с потоком. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1294753/

Comment: Друг, ну ты это, отпишись хоть, видел ответ, не видел, сработало ли, или чего то уточнить?