# Как реализовать параллельную работу телеграм-бота и бесконечного цикла с помощью aiogram? (Python)

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, asyncio

Есть бот, обрабатывающий команды пользователя. Также в коде есть цикл, ежеминутно парсящий данные и при определенных параметрах присылает пользователю сообщение.
Каким образом запустить их одновременно? Через telebot получалось в двух скриптах запустить, но бот гасился через несколько минут. Через aiogram бот работает вроде как корректно, но параллельно боту не выполняется парсинг.

Кусок кода выглядит примерно таким образом:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def process_command(message: types.Message):
    *** обработчик команды ***

def parse():
    *** парсит данные и присылает пользователям ботом ***

def main():
    executor.start_polling(dispatcher=dp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Парсинг в Threading пихать пробовал?

Comment: @Gh0sTG0 нет, хотелось бы пример, как разделить потоки на бота и функцию отвечающую за парсинг

Comment: Примерно вот так, как в ответе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1294753/

Comment: @Gh0sTG0 как то слишком мудрено, я уверен можно сделать это проще, зная нужную команду. Я думал для этого и используется aiogram, иначе какой в нем смысл

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разобрался сам:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(main())
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

В данном случае main() - функция-парсер
dp - Dispatcher()