# Использование одной переменной между разными функциями Python

Tags: python, flask

Могу ли я как то использоваться одну переменную с конкретным значением между двумя изолированными функциями без использования global?
Я использую Flask, каждая страница приложения представляет собой в app.py файле отдельную функцию, мне нужно чтобы к примеру в одной функции в этой переменной выбиралось рандомное число, аля nubmer = random.randint(1, 2048), и чтобы вторая функция потом могла использовать это же чисто из этой переменной без использования global.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1294753/ вот это попробуй почитать ответ. Мб такой класс тебе подойдет (хотя я не уверен, там все же несколько другое).

Comment: Решение зависит от структуры программы, т.е. от того, как между собой взаимодействуют и/или связанны эти функции. Кто и когда их вызывает? В текущем виде вопрос слишком общий и широкий (и требует уточнения)